# Data for site specific path analyzer map is not getting reflected

Tags: path-analyzer

I have created a site specific path analyzer map. But, unfortunately. I am not able to get the data displayed for the same even after 24 hours. In addition to that , I wanted to know how to link the funnel with a site specific map.

Comment: Is the visitor's data getting captured/tracked properly in your sitecore instance ? Are you able to see the tracked data in Sitecore Analytics ? If not, before checking my answer - you should consider looking at the logs for any exceptions related to xDB etc.

Answer (score 1):

After opening Path Analyzer from Sitecore LaunchPad, I used to choose **All Visits** in the site map dropdown menu and then choose the **Vertical** representation as shown below to see the map diagram with paths and nodes,

[image]

If you just want to view a funnel from a site map, check this official Sitecore docs link [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/view-a-path-funnel.html)

Or if you want to link a custom funnel you've created under Marketing control Panel, then see the below steps :

**Step 1 :** Go to `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Funnels` and then create a funnel item (by giving some item name) under the Funnels node.

**Step 2 :** Select the funnel item you just created, and scroll down to the field called **Sequence**. In this field, click edit and then choose the pages in a sequence that you want to track. Funnels help you understand how many users are dropping off along each pages you've selected in this path sequence before they realize a business objective. For example, we create funnels with paths defined from Home page to Cart page to understand where visitors are bouncing off.

[image]

**Step 3 :** Click the **Review** tab in the Sitecore Ribbon area and then click the **Deploy** button, present in the Workflow group.

**EDIT: To view the custom funnel**

Click Funnels at the Map overview Panel found at the right side of the map as shown below. In the dropdown, choose the funnel you created with the sequence. Then click "Set as filter".

[image]

Now, click Apply

[image]

You can now see the path for the **Lead form** funnel (in screenshot) that we created as below,

[image]

Comment: Added how to view the custom funnel in the map in the EDIT section